# Animate text with javascript / Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZYJsK/302/

I want to animate texts like this site : http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

This section ====> [image]

My Js :

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope,$element) {
    var texts = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
    var textToAdd = angular.element("#sizin");
    var count = 0;
    function changeText (){
      textToAdd.text(texts[count]);
        count < 3 ? count++ : count = 0;
    }

    setInterval(changeText,500);
});
```

Any Advice Would be great ? Thanks a million

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: i want to animate it like the website i mentioned i don't know how to

Comment: http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/gFHza check this please , GSAP can do the tricks , have you worked with GSAP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind to scope variable and change it by timer and call `$apply`.

Something like this.

```
$scope.initComVal = '.com';
$scope.comval = '';
function changeText (){
    if($scope.comval.length === $scope.initComVal.length)
        $scope.comval = '';
    else
    {
        $scope.comval = $scope.initComVal.substring(0, $scope.comval.length+1);
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/to61vaL6/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer , how about multi word ?  .com and available ?